# What is the best way to do seed MongoDB in ASP.Net Core 2.2

Tags: c#, mongodb, asp.net-core, .net-core

We are using  ASP.Net Core 2.2 with MongoDB.Driver and want to seed MongoDB. Wondering what is the proper way to seed the database.

Comment: aside: .net core 2.2 is out of support.

Comment: thanks @DanielA.White, how can i seed asp.net core with MongoDb

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing available built-in for this. In short, you'll just take care of stuff like this during app startup, by adding to `Program.cs`. For example:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var host = CreateHostBuilder(args).Build()

    // do something here

    host.Run();
}
```

If you need to do something asynchronous, you can use async Main, and await `host.RunAsync()`:

```
public static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    var host = CreateHostBuilder(args).Build()

    // do something async here

    await host.RunAsync();
}
```

Note that by building the host, you gain access to any services you have registered via `host.Services`, so you can do stuff like `host.Services.GetRequiredService<Foo>()`.